# Конструкции типа „собственное имя + «младший»”

Tags: приложение

Можете ли вы помочь с выбором нормативного знака: дефиса или пробела, — в следующем словосочетании и подобным ему:

„Иванов (-/ ) младший”?

Мои версии:

1. Это сочетание можно рассматривать как *приложение*, в котором **собственное имя** Иванов — главное слово, а „младший” — зависимое, причём являющееся субстантивированным прилагательным. Ну а дефис ставится на основании конструкции „собственное имя + нарицательное существительное”. Сравните, кстати говоря: Иванов-взрослый (здесь „взрослый” — субстантивированное прилагательное).
2. Это просто согласованное прилагательное, стоящее после главного слова. Да, такая конструкция является нестандартной, поскольку обычно прилагательное после определяемого слова является составным именным сказуемым, но можно попробовать провести параллель с терминами из биологии, где также наблюдается данная „диковинка”: „акация белая”, „белка домашняя”.

Примечание: В исходном контексте словосочетание писалось через дефис, на что я и обратил внимание.

Comment: Бот Ботович: _Можете ли вы помочь с выбором нормативного знака: **двоеточия** или пробела..._ === Наверное, Вы хотели написать: _"**дефиса** или пробела"_?

Comment: Ой, извините. Заработался, так сказать. Спасибо за исправление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта оформления:

**Иванов-младший.** **Приложение**, выраженное субстантивированным прилагательным, пишется через дефис в постпозиции.

**Иванов Младший.** Здесь обычное **прилагательное** входит в состав имени собственного и поэтому пишется с прописной буквы.

Примеры:

Вместе с Лехой борются его друзья ― братья Вадик и Артём (**Дрон-старший и Дрон-младший** ― тоже от фамилии)...  Террор несовершеннолетних // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.02.07]

Отметим, что **Феликс Феликсович Юсупов-младший** приходился племянником председателю IV Государственной Думы М.В. Родзянко.

Так, **Плиний Старший** писал, что...  [Александр Голяндин.  «Знание -- сила», 2003]

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и дополнение про прозвище!

Answer (score 1):

> „Иванов (-/ ) младший”?

Правильно:

***Иванов-младший.***

См. [**"Полный академический справочник"**](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp123.php) под. ред. Лопатина:

> **§ 123**... Составные имена (в том числе исторических лиц, святых, фольклорных персонажей и др.), в которых **вторая часть является** не
>   прозвищем, а **нарицательным именем в роли приложения**, пишутся через
>   дефис, напр.: ***Рокфеллер-старший***, Дюма-сын; Илья-пророк,
>   Николай-угодник (и *Никола-угодник*); *Иван-царевич,
>   Иванушка-дурачок.*

Comment: Правильно, если вторая часть не является прозвищем. Если же Ивановы станут легендарными личностями, то их будут писать как Иванов Старший и Иванов Младший, чем они хуже Плиния. А пока еще не стали, в семье могут использовать такое название в шутку.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!